# TSQL QUERY --Get count of server and databases

Tags: t-sql

Suppose there is single table holding the details of all servers,databases and environment. Can anyone help me with the Tsql statement to get the count of servers and databases per environment .

**Sample table fields**

- Servername    ----  A,B,C etc
- Databasename   ---- x ,y ,z etc
- Environment    --- ENV1 ,ENV2 etc

**Expected results**

```
Env              Servercount          dbcount
----------------------------------------------
ENV1              999                  9999
ENV2              111                  1111
```

I believe it can be done by using SQL windows function but not able to form it

Comment: Just looks like you need a `GROUP BY Environment` and two `COUNT(DISTINCT ..)`?

Comment: Thank You , Martin Smith!!. It did the trick .. got the result :)